# Bootstrapping with R

Tags: r

I have some trouble in calculating a confidence interval with bootstrap method using R. Here is a minimal example that I get stuck.

```
library(simpleboot)
set.seed(123)
random <- data.frame(x=runif(10), y=runif(10))
pi <- function(df){4*length(subset(df, x^2 + y^2 < 1)$x)/length(df$x)}
pi.boot <- one.boot(random, pi, 1000) # I got an error here
```

I got an error which says

> Error in `[.data.frame`(x, idx) : undefined columns selected

Would you help me to find out what is wrong with it? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to our site! This question seems to be purely about debugging code, which is off-topic here - see our [help/on-topic]. This site is usually better if your underlying question is inherently statistical, rather than about the code itself.

Comment: It seems to me the issue here isn't with your bootstrap but your function `pi`. Try breaking things down into an absolutely *minimal* reproducible example to work out which part of `pi` isn't working. Then if you haven't worked out the error by then, it'll be in a good form for posting on Stack Overflow. On the other hand, asking folk to debug your entire code because you haven't tried finding where the error is can be considered a bit lazy, but moreover it's unhelpful to future readers - if someone *does* have a issue with bootstraps they don't want to see a Q about subsetting in their search

Comment: Thank you for your comments. The real problem I am facing has more complicated data and function. So I thought this is simple enough (but meaningful) to reproduce the error. (In case of too simple function, I can avoid this error but such avoidance doesn't work in my case.) Anyway it seems better to ask this in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

See if this is what you want:

```
x<-1:nrow(random)
pif <- function(yt,dft){4*length(subset(dft[yt,], x^2 + y^2 < 1)$x)/length(dft[yt,]$x)}
pi.boot <- one.boot(x, pif, 1000,dft=random) # no error 

#print(pi.boot)
boot.ci(pi.boot)  
#hist(pi.boot)

BOOTSTRAP CONFIDENCE INTERVAL CALCULATIONS
Based on 1000 bootstrap replicates

CALL : 
boot.ci(boot.out = pi.boot)

Intervals : 
Level      Normal              Basic         
95%   ( 2.202,  4.194 )   ( 2.400,  4.400 )  

Level     Percentile            BCa          
95%   ( 2.0,  4.0 )   ( 1.6,  3.6 )  
Calculations and Intervals on Original Scale
Warning : BCa Intervals used Extreme Quantiles
Some BCa intervals may be unstable
```